# How to improve this "update" function?

Tags: scala, collections, tail-recursion

Suppose I've got `case class A(x: Int, s: String)` and need to update a `List[A]` using a `Map[Int, String]` like that:

```
def update(as: List[A], map: Map[Int, String]): List[A] = ???

val as = List(A(1, "a"), A(2, "b"), A(3, "c"), A(4, "d"))
val map = Map(2 -> "b1", 4 -> "d1", 5 -> "e", 6 -> "f")
update(as, map) // List(A(1, "a"), A(2, "b1"), A(3, "c"), A(4, "d1"))
```

I am writing `update` like that:

```
def update(as: List[A], map: Map[Int, String]): List[A] = {

  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(acc: List[A], rest: List[A], map: Map[Int, String]): List[A] = rest match {
    case Nil => acc
    case as => as.span(a => !map.contains(a.x)) match {
      case (xs, Nil) => xs ++ acc
      case (xs, y :: ys) => loop((y.copy(s = map(y.x)) +: xs) ++ acc, ys, map - y.x)
    }
  }

  loop(Nil, as, map).reverse
}
```

This function works fine but it's suboptimal because it continues iterating over the input list when `map` is empty. Besides, it looks overcomplicated. How would you suggest improve this `update` function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can not make any supposition about the **List** and the **Map**. Then the best is to just iterate the former, juts once and in the simplest way possible; that is, using the `map` function.

```scala
list.map { a =>
  map
    .get(key = a.x)
    .fold(ifEmpty = a) { s =>
      a.copy(s = s)
   }
}
```

However, if and only if, you can be sure that most of the time:

1. The **List** will be big.
2. The **Map** will be small.
3. The keys in the **Map** are a subset of the values in the **List**.
4. And all operations will be closer to the head of the **List** rather than the tail.

Then, you could use the following approach which should be more efficient in such cases.

```scala
def optimizedUpdate(data: List[A], updates: Map[Int, String]): List[A] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remaining: List[A], map: Map[Int, String], acc: List[A]): List[A] =
    if (map.isEmpty) acc reverse_::: remaining
    else remaining match {
      case a :: as =>
        map.get(key = a.x) match {
          case None =>
            loop(
              remaining = as,
              map,
              a :: acc
            )
          
          case Some(s) =>
            loop(
              remaining = as,
              map = map - a.x,
              a.copy(s = s) :: acc
            )
        }
      
      case Nil =>
        acc.reverse
    }
  
  loop(remaining = data, map = updates, acc = List.empty)
}
```

However note that the code is not only longer and more difficult to understand.
It is actually more inefficient than the `map` solution *(if the conditions are not meet)*; this is because the stdlib implementation *"cheats"* and constructs the **List** my mutating its `tail` instead of building it backwards and then `reversing` it as we did.

In any case, as with any things performance, the only real answer is to benchmark.
But, I would go with the `map` solution just for clarity or with a mutable approach if you really need speed.

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/JeDiHNxYQk6C3Ekjy6lMvg/5)*.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
def update(as: List[A], map: Map[Int, String]): List[A] =
  as.foldLeft(List.empty[A]) { (agg, elem) =>
    val newA = map
      .get(elem.x)
      .map(a => elem.copy(s = a))
      .getOrElse(elem)
    newA :: agg
  }.reverse
```